# Flask 404 Not Found ( 33mGET / HTTP/1.1 [0m" 404 - )

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create my first script with flask.

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Blueprint, request

prediction_app = Blueprint('prediction_app', __name__)

@prediction_app.route('/health', methods=['GET'])
def health():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return 'ok'

def create_app() -> Flask:
    """Create a flask app instance."""

    flask_app = Flask('ml_api')

    # import blueprints
    flask_app.register_blueprint(prediction_app)

    return flask_app

application = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

I run this code as *python run.py* and I am getting ***"Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/"***.
I go to this link and I am getting instead of ***"ok"*** a page with the next error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Command promt gives the following output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jun/2020 16:59:25] "[33mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: The path you requested with your request is `/`. In your Application, you defined a route for `/health`. So your server does not know how to handle `/` and therefore returns the `404`. Please try `http://127.0.0.1:5000/health`

Comment: hit it here `/health`

Comment: @mottek I tried to change it to "@prediction_app.route('/http://127.0.0.1:5000/health', methods=['GET'])" bit I am getting the same result: 404 Not Found

Comment: @illuminates Your code is fine, please revert the change you just made. I meant to access your app using the URL `http://127.0.0.1:5000/health` with whatever tool you are using (curl, browser, ...)

Comment: @mottek Thanks. I got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a default route (`/`) defined; did you try pointing your browser at `http://localhost:5000/health`? That's the route you did define.

(`localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are typically equivalent, by the way...)

Comment: @illuminates a clarification: I didn't mean to change the code, just what you type into the browser. Your exact code works for me when I go to `http://localhost:5000/health`